# Why does using broadcast increase time?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is the pseudocode:

```
case class IpDB(startIp: Long, endIp: Long, company: String)
def ipMap(line: Array[String]):
    val Array(startIp, endIp, company) = line
    IpDB(startIp.toLong, endIp.toLong, company)
// The ip-db is just 300M in raw format.
// format of ip-data from s3:
// 100000 200000 GOOGLE
val ipData = sc.broadcast(sc.textFile("s3://....").map(_.split("\t", -1)).map(ipMap).collect().sortWith(_.startIp < _.startIp)).value

val dataA = sc.textFile("s3://...").map((ip, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
val dataB = sc.textFile("s3://...").map((ip, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_)

// will do ip company lookup here
dataA.fullOuterJoin(dataB).map(doIpCompanyLookUp(ipData, _)).collect()
```

The code just gets ip data from input sources, then find its company after join.
Here is my question:

This code will run 2-3 minutes in production, but when removing the broadcast data(just do join on two data), it just cost less than 1 minute.And when i look the ui of spark, i found that gc time may be the problem.

Here is the setting to run this job:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 4g --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 8800m --executor-cores 4 --class ... XX.jar
```

This job is running on aws emr spark cluster

```
spark version: 1.6.1
10 m3.xlarge.
```

1. How can solve this problem(reduce running time)?
2. Which memory does broadcast data consume in spark?
3. Why the running time does not change when i change the executor-memory? i try to use 5*m3.2xlarge and --executor-memory 16g, no significant changes on total running time with broadcast data.

update:

```
case class IpDB(startIp: Long, endIp: Long, company: String)
def ipMap(line: Array[String]):
    val Array(startIp, endIp, company) = line
    IpDB(startIp.toLong, endIp.toLong, company)
// The ip-db is just 300M in raw format.
// format of ip-data from s3:
// 100000 200000 GOOGLE
val dataA = sc.textFile("s3://...").map((ip, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
val dataB = sc.textFile("s3://...").map((ip, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_)

// will do ip company lookup here
val joinResult = dataA.fullOuterJoin(dataB)
val ipData = sc.broadcast(sc.textFile("s3://....").map(_.split("\t", -1)).map(ipMap).collect().sortWith(_.startIp < _.startIp)).value
joinResult.map(doIpCompanyLookUp(ipData, _)).collect()
```

just move the generation and broadcast of ip-company data after `dataA.fullOuterJoin(dataB)`.The running time reduce a lot.

update2.
since the production code is quite complicate which is different form the pseudocode above, after little change on the order of the code, the program runs faster, but I am not sure the key to the problem is the position to init broadcast data.

Comment: Maybe this is a little naive, but the broadcast start sending the 300M around the network and clogs the executors. Can you try to find the DAG?

Answer (score 0):

Without much thinking about your code the line:

```
val ipData = sc.broadcast(sc.textFile("s3://....").map(_.split("\t", -1)).map(ipMap).collect().sortWith(_.startIp < _.startIp)).value
```

worries me a LOT.

You're building a distributed RDD using `sc.textFile` only to make it local (to the driver) by `collect()` followed by making it distributed again and available to the executors by `sc.broadcast` (!) As you can see there are a lot of sending data back and forth.

You'd be better off `cache`ing the IP data so it stays in memory, but doing:

```
sc.textFile("s3://....").map(_.split("\t", -1)).map(ipMap).cache
```

Comment: What happens when you replace `broadcast` with `cache` for the whole ip-company data? How does this impact the time?

Comment: Since I need to do ip-company lookup, data type of RDD[IpDB] can't help with it. That's why i need to broadcast all the data to make sure that all the executor has a copy of ip-company data.Just make sure I get the difference between `broadcast` and `cache`. So I could not use `cache` in the program to make it work.